# Issues with integrating Quill and ShareDB with `quill-cursors`

Tags: quill, sharejs

I'm trying to integrate Quill and ShareDB with a package called `quill-cursors` found here. The example is available here: `https://github.com/pedrosanta/quill-sharedb-cursors.` The demo works well, but when running on my local machine, I've encountered the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function.` Why might that be?

Comment: Where this error occurs ? On client side ? On server side ? Please give more clues in order to help you